# Remove multiple occurrence in a row from a certain character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I want to remove multiple `'.'` in a row to a single `'.'` in Python.

This is my code, that i come up with:

```
# remove multiple occurrences of '.'
string = "FOO...BAR......FOO..BAR.FOO"
last_char = None
new_string = ""
for char in string:
    if not (last_char == '.' and char == '.'):
        new_string += char
    last_char = char
string = new_string
print(string)
```

and it is indeed doing what i want it to do, but I think there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

```
>>> FOO.BAR.FOO.BAR.FOO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it easier to do with a regex (`re` module) with pattern `"\.+"` which means an

- a dot `\.`
- which repeats between 1 to infinite amount of times `+`

```
import re

string = "FOO...BAR......FOO..BAR.FOO"
string = re.sub(r"\.+", '.', string)
print(string)  # FOO.BAR.FOO.BAR.FOO
```

---

Or just replace all 2 dots, by one, until you have no more 2 dots together

```
string = "FOO...BAR......FOO..BAR.FOO"
while string.find('..') >= 0:
    string = string.replace("..", ".")
print(string)  # FOO.BAR.FOO.BAR.FOO
```

Comment: Thank you! I am looking into regex now. But why exactly is the '\' needed? What would happen without?

Comment: @manman in regex, the dot means "any character", so you need to escape it with `\` to get the real dot

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "FOO...BAR......FOO..BAR.FOO"

print (".".join([x for x in string.split(".") if x]))
```

Output:

```
FOO.BAR.FOO.BAR.FOO
```

You split at any given character, and join back to string if the list element is not null with the same given character as delimiter. So you replace all multiple occurrences of the given character by a single one.

Step by step:

```
string = "FOO...BAR......FOO..BAR.FOO"

print ([x for x in string.split(".")])

print ([x for x in string.split(".") if x])

print (".".join([x for x in string.split(".") if x]))
```

Output:

```
['FOO', '', '', 'BAR', '', '', '', '', '', 'FOO', '', 'BAR', 'FOO']
['FOO', 'BAR', 'FOO', 'BAR', 'FOO']
FOO.BAR.FOO.BAR.FOO
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, thank you for your input. But it is way over my head. 
I get that you split the string at '.' and iterate through that list without '.' but everything around I don't understand.

Comment: thank you. now i fully understand it! :-)